# Game centre issues when viewing leaderboard and scores

Tags: ios, swift, center, scene

I've integrated Game Centre into my app the following way:

When the game loads

```
func authPlayer(){
    let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {
        (view, error) in

        if view != nil {

            self.present(view!, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        else {

            print(GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().isAuthenticated)

        }


    }
}
```

And then in the gameOver scene:

```
func saveHighscore(_ number : Int){

    if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().isAuthenticated {

        let scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "...")

        scoreReporter.value = Int64(number)

        let scoreArray : [GKScore] = [scoreReporter]

        GKScore.report(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: nil)

    }


}
func showLeaderboard() {
    let gameCenter = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gameCenter.gameCenterDelegate = self
    gameCenter.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.leaderboards
    if let gameViewController = self.view?.window?.rootViewController {
        gameViewController.show(gameCenter, sender: self)
        gameViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(gameCenter, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Some devices can't find the leaderboard, other devices can find it but only have their score showing etc.
Have I missed something?
Authenticating works fine.

Comment: I also have this in the gamescene.       var score = UserDefaults().integer(forKey: "HIGHSCORE")